# Binary Classification on small dataset < 200 samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-mining, prediction

I have a dataset consisting of 181 samples and 10 features and one target variable. The 10 features are numeric and continuous in nature. I have to perform binary classification. I have done the following work:-

```
I have performed 3 Fold cross validation and got following accuracy results using various models:-

LinearSVC:
0.873
DecisionTreeClassifier:
0.840
Gaussian Naive Bayes:
0.845
Logistic Regression:
0.867
Gradient Boosting Classifier
0.867
Support vector classifier rbf:
0.818
Random forest:
0.867
K-nearest-neighbors:
0.823
```

Please guide me how could I choose the best model for this size of dataset and make sure my model is not overfitting ? I have followed the steps from sklearn map http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/

Comment: This isn't really about programming.  Try posting this on [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [data science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can never eliminate it completely especially with such a small sample.

Firstly cross validate - which you are already doing. Secondly use default parameters. If you use the output of cross-validation to change the parameters then you are likely to overfit.

Finally, look at the whole confusion matrix or a metric that summarises this such as f1 rather than accuracy. If 99% of people don't have cancer then a model that predicts nobody has cancer is 99% accurate but not very helpful.